# Idiom, phrase, or word for "no clear division"

Tags: phrase-requests, synonyms, idiom-requests

Example: "There is no clear division between a liquid and a solid. The soggy soil we are standing on is a case in point. So is the yogurt you're having."

What's an idiom, phrase, or word for "no clear division"?

I thought of "fine line", but it doesn't seem to be appropriate in this case; a "fine line" is usually used in a cautionary way, with the second object being unfavorable in some way - for example, "There is a fine line between being funny and being immature."

Comment: "A thin line" maybe? If there's a thin line between things, it's hard to distinguish them.

Comment: Gray, fuzzy line.

Comment: ("Fine line" or "thin line" can imply distinct, just difficult to discern without careful examination.)

Comment: Aside.  There are some scientific names for these "transition" zones.  You can look them up.  I found one on wiki - "mesophase". (Which I would never use in prose.)

Answer (score 1):

Probably ***indistinct*** may suit your context:

> Not clearly or sharply delineated: an indistinct pattern; indistinct shapes in the gloom.

From the Free Dictionary

- An indistinct mass of liquid and solid.

Answer (score 1):

Try *continuum*.

> **Continuum** *noun*
>   A continuous sequence in which adjacent elements are not perceptibly different from each other, but the extremes are quite distinct: *a continuum of special educational needs*
>   [- ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/continuum)

Here's an example from [MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/continuum):

> His motives for volunteering lie somewhere on the continuum between charitable and self-serving.

In your example, you could say, "Liquids and solids are part of a continuum." or following the form of your example more directly, "There is a continuum between a liquid and a solid."

Answer (score 1):

One idiomatic expression for this is **much of a muchness**

> (idiomatic) Of two or more things, having little difference of any significance between them.

[Source](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/much_of_a_muchness)

Answer (score 1):

You can perhaps say ***[blur](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/blur)***, as in *blurring the lines*

> to make the ​difference between two things less ​clear, or to make it ​difficult to ​see the ​exact ​truth about something
>
> *This ​film **blurs** the ​line/​distinction/​boundary between ​reality and ​fantasy.*

[Cambridge Online]

**Usage:**

> The soggy soil that we are standing on ***blurs*** the line between liquid and solid. So does the Yogurt you are having!